# Is there a random command for Boolean variables in Unity C#

Tags: unity, c#, random, boolean

Can you randomly choose a Boolean's value in Unity C#. I tried random.range, but it only works with floats. Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
Boolean = (random boolean value command)(false, true);
if(Boolean = true){
    Debug.Log("It's true!")
} else{
    Debug.Log("It's false!")
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: No need for `if(boolean==true)` . Just use if(boolean)

Comment: @SanSolo Right, so it's basically an alternative to `boolean = true`.

Comment: Keep in mind that a vast majority of your C# questions are not specific to game development. Unity doesn't use a special version of C#.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

SanSolo answer is good and he get my +1.

Using unity [Random.value](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random-value.html) here is a one line command:

```
bool Boolean  = (Random.value > 0.5f);
```

Comment: A guy from unity forum moderators said, that this variant is better than `.Range(0,2)` here (https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/random-randomboolean-function.83220/#post-1139598)

Answer (score 7):

Random.Range will return an integer if both min and max are integers. `Random.Range(0,2)` will return either one or zero. You could use it like this:

```
Boolean boolValue = (Random.Range(0, 2) == 0);
if(boolValue == true){
    Debug.Log("It's true!");
} else{
    Debug.Log("It's false!");
}
```